# не переходит в папку при создании репозитория

Tags: windows, cmd

Хочу создать репозиторий git
Прописываю `cd F:\courseer_web\2_week` для перехода в папку с проектом, но у консоли ноль реакции
Подскажите что я делаю не так

Comment: может потому сто сначала нужно сделать `F:` в консоли?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно добавить флаг `/d` (служит для перехода в папку на другом диске, *d - drive*. Не путать с *d* в самой команде `cd`, где она означает *directory*)

```
cd /d F:\courseer_web\2_week
```

Или как указали в комментарии сначала перейти на другой диск (`F:`), а потом уже сменить папку.